# Find vs Get у модели (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Какая разница между этими кусками кода. Articles -- модель

```
   $article = Articles::find($id);
   $article = Articles::all()->toArray()->get($id);
```

Первый способ работает в php страничке: {{article['title']}}
А второй способ нет. Когда будет работать второй способ и какая разница между этими способами извлечениями даных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- выбираете все записи - используйте `all()`
- используете условия - вызывайте `get()`
- знаете `id` - `find()`, `findOrFail()` и т.п.

После `toArray()` у вас массив. Никаких методов у него нет.
*Другими словами, второй вариант работать не будет вообще.*

см. [Eloquent::Adding Additional Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models)